# How do I make virtual methods of classes that inherit the same base class figure out what to do with their argument?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

Here it is explained in code:

```
//Sphere and Box inherit from IShape
//
//Sphere methods:
//bool Sphere::Intersect(Sphere* sphere)
//bool Sphere::Intersect(Box* box);
//
//Box methods:
//bool Box::Intersect(Sphere* sphere)
//bool Box::Intersect(Box* box)

IShape* shapeA;
IShape* shapeB;

shapeA= new Sphere();
shapeB= new Box();

bool areTheyIntersecting = shapeA->Intersect(shapeB); //problem is here?
```

Will such a way of using polymorphism ever work or must I look for another way to get the classes recognize each-other's types so they know the proper method to call?

Comment: You need _double dispatch_ here...

Comment: Why not just use static typing? IShape is a really bad idea.

Comment: so I can put them all(the IShape variables) in 1 array later on to more easily make a CompositeShape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double dispatch is generally used through the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), but in your case it's a bit weird because the visitor is the element itself... hang on tight!

The idea, in a nutshell:

- start from pair of `IShape` / `IShape`, named `left` and `right` from now on
- invoke the `intersect` method on `left` passing `right` as argument, within the `intersect` method `left` knows it *exact* type (it's a `Sphere`!) and informs `right` about it by invoking the right overload of `intersect` on `right` (the one taking a `Sphere`)
- within the `intersect` call on `right`, `right` knows its exact type and *hey* we passed the exact type of `left` too, so now we know them all!

A simple implementation:

```
class IShape {
public:
    virtual ~IShape() {}

    virtual bool intersect(IShape const& other) const = 0;

    virtual bool intersect(Box const& other) const = 0;
    virtual bool intersect(Sphere const& other) const = 0;
}; // class IShape

class Box: public IShape {
public:
    virtual bool intersect(IShape const& other) const override {
        std::cout << "-> Box::intersect(IShape)\n";
        return other.intersect(*this);
    }

    virtual bool intersect(Box const& other) const override {
        std::cout << "-> Box::intersect(Box)\n";
        /* compute intersection of two boxes */
        return false;
    }

    virtual bool intersect(Sphere const& other) const override {
        std::cout << "-> Box::intersect(Sphere)\n";
        /* compute intersection of a box and a sphere */
        return false;
    }
}; // class Box

// Likewise implementation of Sphere
```

A [complete implementation](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2X3kgs%242) gives this output:

```
int main() {
   Box const box;
   Sphere const sphere;
   IShape const& ibox = box;
   IShape const& isphere = sphere;


   box.intersect(sphere);
   // output
   // -> Box::intersect(Sphere)


   ibox.intersect(sphere);
   // output
   // -> Box::intersect(Sphere)


   sphere.intersect(ibox);
   // output
   // -> Sphere::intersect(IShape)
   // -> Box::intersect(Sphere)


   isphere.intersect(ibox);
   // output
   // -> Sphere::intersect(IShape)
   // -> Box::intersect(Sphere)
}
```

This strategy is named double dispatch because there are two consecutive double dispatches when starting from IShape/IShape, one dispatch per variable for which the dynamic type need be "deduced".

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are describing is known as double dispatch.  There are many solutions.  They all suck in various ways.

The fundamental reason why they suck is that double dispatch grows in size quadratically with the number of types, and writing a quadratic amount of code always sucks.

One approach is to figure out a way to reduce the general double dispatch to a single dispatch with a few special cases (like sphere sphere).

If the number of types is limited, you can have two sets of virtual functions.  The first takes other as an abstract base class.  The other set of functions has each implementation class as a possible argument.  The abstract base class is implemented in each implementation calls the other other object with this as the first argument on the "other set of functions" that do not take the abstract base as an argument.

Ie, `collide(base* other)` calls `other->collideSpecific (this)`.

CRTP can be used to reduce some of the boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario you need something called double-dispatch. Take a look at More Effective C++ by Scott Meyers and Modern C++ Design by Alexendrescu.

Here is another article that also discusses it
http://www.drdobbs.com/double-dispatch-revisited/184405527

Answer (score 1):

One way around it is to have uint variable declared in each class(or extractable from class, see below) and a virtual function returning this variable for the object in question. I'd then declare a hash of `<std::pair<uint,uint>,std::function<bool(IShape*, IShape*)>>`

The hash will contain functions that know how to deal with particular object types and typical call will be like:

```
auto key = std::pair<uint,uint>(obj1.typeNumber(), obj2.typenumber())
funchash[key](obj1, obj2);
```

The number does not even need to be hardcoded as shown in this manual :
http://shaderop.com/2010/09/uniquely-identifying-types-in-c-without-using-rtti/index.html
This essentially shows how to make class name into type id.

Sure, this still means a lot of boilerplate but I don't like having it inside my classes and this type mechanism is kinda useful itself anyway.

Comment: This is actually a re-implementation of virtual dispatch; without the compiler support. Suitable for closed hierarchies, can be extended to arbitrary ones provided you get a way to generate the IDs and a way to get register the methods in the look-up table.

Comment: I like this approach because it means neither box nor sphere have to know of each other's structure in order to calculate intersection. Having free functions to take care of these things is really handy, especially since you can change them at runtime